# Socket.io - Message is not Emitted when user sends a message

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Expected Result: User is asked to Enter a Room name to join, Once entered, User is redirected to that room and can send messages to the users within that room.

Problem: User is able to join the room but when send button is clicked, no messages are sent, but when i tried the same code w/o the room functionality, it works

Note: I am using -  socket.to(Room).emit - to emit to the rooms user has joined.

Server Side :

```
const express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')

const app = express()
const server = app.listen(4000, () => {
 console.log('Listening to Port on 4000')
})

app.use(express.static('public'))
const io = socket(server)

io.on('connect', (socket)=> {
 console.log(socket.id)
 // Room Name Variable
 var Room;

 socket.on('RoomName', function(Name) {
  Room = Name.Room
  console.log(Room)
  socket.join(Room, () => {
   console.log('Room Joined - ' + Room)
  })
 })

 socket.on('newMessageToServer', function(Msg) {
  console.log(Msg)
  socket.to(Room).emit('messageToClients', Msg)
 })
})
```

Client Side(Index Page) -

```
const Socket = io('http://localhost:4000')

// Variables
const InputField = document.querySelector('.RoomName')
const InputBtn = document.querySelector('.Btn')

// Socket Room Setup
InputBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 Socket.emit('RoomName', {Room: InputField.value})
})
```

Client Side(Chat Room Page - The Page user is redirected to when Room name is submitted) -

```
const Socket = io('http://localhost:4000')

// Variables
const InputField = document.querySelector('.Input')
const InputBtn = document.querySelector('.Btn')
const MessageUl = document.querySelector('.Messages')

const DataHandle = prompt('Username Handle')

// Event Listeners
InputBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 Socket.emit('newMessageToServer', {Username: DataHandle, Message: InputField.value})
 InputField.value = ''
})

Socket.on('messageToClients', function(Msg) {
 MessageUl.innerHTML += '<li><span>' + Msg.Username + '</span>' + Msg.Message + '</li>' 
})
```

[Screenshot of Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JhAP.png)

Comment: If you "redirect", its going to lose the room as its a new connection, there is no state.

Comment: Is it possible to change the page w/o losing the connection ?